# Change properties of samples during playtime

Tags: java, audio, jsyn

I'm trying to find a way to change properties of a sample during playtime when certain events are happening, e.g. raise the volume or play it faster.

Is that possible using [Jsyn](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/)? Or are there other tools out there to do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to JSyn documentation, and more specifically to [their presentation slide](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/slides/sl_evbuf2.html), there is an event buffer which may support that kind of feature ... Take a look at the birds example (http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/examples/index.php) which exposes variable noise generation ...

Answer (score 0):

JSyn has a unit generator for playing samples called VariableRateDataReader. You can change the rate at which a sample is played by setting the rate port. It also has an amplitude port.

http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/docs/javadocs/com/jsyn/unitgen/VariableRateDataReader.html

Here are the key steps:

```
// Load the sample.
FloatSample sample = SampleLoader.loadFloatSample(sampleFile);
// Create a player.
synth.add(samplePlayer = new VariableRateMonoReader());
// Set the rate to 70% of normal
samplePlayer.rate.set(sample.getFrameRate() * 0.7);
// Set the amplitude to 50% of normal
samplePlayer.amplitude.set(0.5);
// Queue the sample to the player.
samplePlayer.dataQueue.queue(sample);
```

Here is an example program that loads and plays a sample:

https://github.com/philburk/jsyn/blob/master/tests/com/jsyn/examples/PlaySample.java